# Do Math on Two Scalar Queries in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the difference of two sum() queries.  This is the idea of the code I'm trying to figure out.

```
(SELECT sum(depamt)  FROM Daily1) - (SELECT sum(depamt)  FROM Daily2)
```

I tried declaring variables but I couldn't get the result of the select into the variables.   Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put a `SELECT` in front:

```
SELECT (SELECT sum(depamt) FROM Daily1) - (SELECT sum(depamt) FROM Daily2);
```

I prefer putting subqueries in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT sum1 - sum2
FROM (SELECT sum(depamt) as sum1 FROM Daily1) x CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT sum(depamt) as sum2 FROM Daily2) y;
```

This allows you to choose each value individually, if you like.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon.  Why would you use the cross join?  Just so you have the results of the two queries together?

Comment: @Missy . . . It allows you to see each value in the calculation if you want, without repeating the subquery.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon.  I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

> I tried declaring variables but I couldn't get the result of the
>   select into the variables. Is there any way of doing this?

To Do it **using Variables**:

```
Declare @Sum1 int, @Sum2 int

SELECT  @Sum1 = sum(depamt) FROM Daily1
SELECT  @Sum2 = sum(depamt) FROM Daily2

Select  @Sum1 -  @Sum2
```